# DSS won't stream 3GP's encoded with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have setup Darwin Streaming Server which streams the included sample 3GP files pretty well. However when I try to encode my own 3GPs using FFMPEG and stream them, it doesn't work. (I test the streaming using VLC Player).

Here is the command I use for encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv -acodec aac -ar 22050 -ab 128kb -vcodec mpeg4 -b 256k -mbd 2 -flags +4mv+aic -trellis 1 -cmp 1 -y test.3gp
```

Do I need a special way to encode the 3gp's for streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSS has no idea about file content. So, you have to "hint" (or give an idea to the server how to stream your file) media file. You can use M4Box for hinting - http://gpac.sourceforge.net/doc_mp4box.php